# how to output data in hbs file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

index.hbs code:
This is index.hbs file where i pass data from index.js file.

````
```{{# each products}}
<div class="row">
{{# each this}}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{imagePath}}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                <p class="description">{{description}}</p>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="price pull-left">{{price}}</div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
{{/each}}```
````

> index.js code:

```
var products=Product.find(function(err,docs){
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products:docs });    
});
```

> data in mongob Schema is like this

```
var products= [
new Product
({
    imagePath:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
    title:'Gothic video games',
    description:'Awesome Game!!',
    price: 20
    }),
new Product({
    imagePath:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
    title:'Gothic video games',
    description:'Awesome Game!!',
    price: 20
    }),
    new Product({
    imagePath:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
    title:'Gothic video games',
    description:'Awesome Game!!',
    price: 20
    }),
    new Product({
    imagePath:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
    title:'Gothic video games',
    description:'Awesome Game!!',
    price: 20
    }),
    new Product({
    imagePath:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
    title:'Gothic video games',
    description:'Awesome Game!!',
    price: 20
    })
        
    ];
```

The result shows five empty column divs  and then one column div with data. Please share its solution.

Comment: The inner {{# each this}} looks unnecessary? Or maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between # and each, should be #each and NOT # each.

eg

`{{#each products}}`

And you DONT need 2 #each, just 1 is enough. Remove {{# each this}} as its not needed.

```
{{#each products}}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{imagePath}}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                <p class="description">{{description}}</p>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="price pull-left">{{price}}</div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

So you're getting each products, and displaying its field. If you want to use 'this', then you can do eg {{this.imagePath}}, but I do believe it's not required as it works either way. You can test it yourself and it should work with, or without this, but it's easier to read as you know what it's referring to.